# XSLT dynamically filter on multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and trying to figure out how to use it to turn this XML:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <role>Parent</role>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <city>Springfield</city>
                <state>MA</state>
                <unimportant-field>123</unimportant-field>
            </location>
            <location>
                <city>Chicago</city>
                <state>IL</state>
                <unimportant-field>456</unimportant-field>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </person>
    <person>
        <role>Child</role>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <city>Springfield</city>
                <state>IL</state>
                <unimportant-field>789</unimportant-field>
            </location>
            <location>
                <city>Chicago</city>
                <state>IL</state>
                <unimportant-field>000</unimportant-field>
            </location>
            <location>
                <city>Washington</city>
                <state>DC</state>
                <unimportant-field>555</unimportant-field>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </person>
</people>
```

Into

```
<people>
    <person>
        <role>Parent</role>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <city>Springfield</city>
                <state>MA</state>
                <unimportant-field>123</unimportant-field>
            </location>
            <location>
                <city>Chicago</city>
                <state>IL</state>
                <unimportant-field>456</unimportant-field>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </person>
    <person>
        <role>Child</role>
        <lastname>Smith</lastname>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <city>Chicago</city>
                <state>IL</state>
                <unimportant-field>000</unimportant-field>
            </location>
        </locations>
    </person>
</people>
```

Basically what is going on is that there is a pseudo hierarchy where I need to filter out locations on the "child" elements that don't also exist in the "parent" element. The child elements are related to their parent by lastname. However there is "unimportant-field" in each location that won't match between parent and child, but shouldn't affect the filtering.

Right now I'm trying to use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/people">
        <people>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
        </people>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="person">
        <person>
            <xsl:copy-of select="role" /> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="lastname" /> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="locations"/>
        </person>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="locations">
        <locations>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="location[city = /people/person[role = 'Parent' and lastname = current()/../lastname]/locations/location/city and state = /people/person[role = 'Parent' and lastname = current()/../lastname]/locations/location/state]"/>
        </locations>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="location">
        <location>
            <xsl:copy-of select="city" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="state" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="unimportant-field" />
        </location>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue is that it is retaining the Springfield, IL element in the child because it is independently checking if the city exists anywhere in the parent and if the state exists anywhere in the parent. What I need to do is figure out if the combination of city and state exists on single location in the parent, while still ignoring "unimportant-field". I'm not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="parent-location" match="person[role='Parent']/locations/location" use="concat(../../lastname, '|', city, '|', state)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person[role='Child']/locations/location[not(key('parent-location', concat(../../lastname, '|', city, '|', state)))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems to work, I'm not fully understanding how it works though. I get that you are creating the parent-location key that contains the data I need to filter on, and then at the bottom checking if the child element locations match those keys. Why the `not()` function though? Wouldn't the `key()` function return true if there is a match in the parent?

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out. The second `<xsl:template />` element at the bottom is not supposed to match the location elements we want to keep. It's matching the elements to remove. It causes them to be removed by defining an empty template for them.