# Write Junit test for applying XSLT on XML Using TransformerFactory

Tags: java, xml, xslt, junit

I am new to Junit Test, I have an xml file and xslt file as follow:

File.xml

```
<people>
<person>
    <role>Parent</role>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <locations>
        <location>
            <city>Springfield</city>
            <state>MA</state>
            <unimportant-field>123</unimportant-field>
        </location>
        <location>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <unimportant-field>456</unimportant-field>
        </location>
    </locations>
</person>
<person>
    <role>Child</role>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    <locations>
        <location>
            <city>Springfield</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <unimportant-field>789</unimportant-field>
        </location>
        <location>
            <city>Chicago</city>
            <state>IL</state>
            <unimportant-field>000</unimportant-field>
        </location>
        <location>
            <city>Washington</city>
            <state>DC</state>
            <unimportant-field>555</unimportant-field>
        </location>
    </locations>
</person>
```

The XSLT file is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="parent-location" match="person[role='Parent']/locations/location" use="concat(../../lastname, '|', city, '|', state)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person[role='Child']/locations/location[not(key('parent-location', concat(../../lastname, '|', city, '|', state)))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the java code that I am using to apply the above XSLT on XML.

```
public class ApplyXSLT {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws TransformerException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public  void process()throws FileNotFoundException, TransformerException
    {
        InputStream file1 = new FileInputStream("file.xml");
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("file.xslt"));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(file1), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("output.xml")));

    }
}
```

I am not sure how to write a Junit test for the above, if anyone can guide me. I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you related to [@KPD](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2077574/kpd)? You seem to have the same XML+XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730940/xslt-dynamically-filter-on-multiple-elements/25731192#25731192

Comment: @michael.hor257k I copied that while searching stack overflow.

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you guide me how to write the testcase for the process method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is most recommended that you write Junit tests to test API utilities. I mean, you should first code a full-semantic abstraction: A class with properly named methods, parameters, and return values. The standard method main does not have any semantics: You cannot know what it does (its name has no specific meaning), nor how many parameters it requires, nor where it produces its results.

So, when you have a class like this:

```
public class MyTransformer 
{
    public void transform(InputStream in, OutputStream out) 
    throws IOException, TransformException
    {...}
}
// If needed, You could also add a main method which delegates over the transform method.
```

... you may code your Junit tester like this:

```
public class MyTransformerTest
{
    // Transforms an existing file producing the result in memory,
    // and compares it with an existing, expected output file.
    private void test(String inputFilename, String expectedOutputFilename)
        throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new MyTransformer().transform(new FileInputStream(inputFilename), out);
            String expectedResult=readFileAsString(expectedOutputFilename);
            assertEquals("File '" + inputFilename + "' was not transformed OK", expectedResult, out.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
        }
        catch (TransformerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail(e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmpty()
        throws IOException
    {
        test("empty-input.xml", "empty-output.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnePersons()
        throws IOException
    {
        test("one-persons-input.xml", "one-persons-output.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwoPersons()
        throws IOException
    {
        test("two-persons-input.xml", "two-persons-output.xml");
    }
}
```

Not that this tester is based on a general purpose *test* method which tests any file. So, you just have to write an input file and an expected output file for each case you are interested on.

This technique will ease for you the future maintainment of the tester: Rembember that every time you'll find a bug, first of all you'll have to add a method in the tester to reproduce it (which initially will fail, of corse). Then fix the code, and run the tester again until it doesn't fail.

One more note: I usually leave the IOExceptions in the throws clause, without catching them. This is because this exception is not your code's fault. So, it is not interesting to your tests. If an IOException arises while the tester is executing, it means that no input or output file could be instantiated: It occurred *before* your code was executed.

Comment: I have made that main class into a method, how can you write a unit test for the process() method @little santi